# Select only one of two selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a containing jQuery object `$c` that has multiple elements in it that contain elements with classnames *tmpSelected* and *selected*, I would like to select only one element from `$c` for each classname, preferably *tmpSelected*. The markup is a complex version of this:

```
<ul id="a">
    <li class="selected"><a href="foo">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="bar">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="baz">Baz</a></li>
    <li><a href="biz">Biz</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="b">
    <li><a href="woo">Woo</a></li>
    <li><a href="war">War</a></li>
    <li class="tmpSelected"><a href="waz">Waz</a></li>
    <li><a href="wiz">Wiz</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="c">
    <li class="selected"><a href="xuu">Xuu</a></li>
    <li class="tmpSelected"><a href="xur">Xur</a></li>
    <li><a href="xuz">Xuz</a></li>
    <li><a href="xyz">Xyz</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this case what I want to end up with is `$("#a > .selected, #b > .tmpSelected, #c > .tmpSelected")` – I want to avoid the `.selected` element if it has a sibling of `.tmpSelected`, and I don't want to select more than one child element for each member of `$c` where `$c = $("#a, #b, #c")`.

So this is what I came up with:

```
var $c = $("#a, #b, #c");
var $selected = $c.map(function (idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var $tmpSel = $el.children(".tmpSelected");
    return $tmpSel.length ? $tmpSel : $el.children(".selected");
});
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this without explicit looping? (P.S. - It's fine to return an empty selector when no `.tmpSelected` or `.selected` child exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a selector but it is pretty messy.  I believe it gives the correct solution:

```
$("ul > li.tmpSelected, ul:not(:has(li.tmpSelected)) > li.selected");
```

First off you look for and `.tmpSelected` elements.  Then you look for any `ul` that only have `.selected` elements. The `:has` selector looks for the child and I use the `:not` selector to find `ul` elements.  Then I simply grab the children `selected` elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCvAp/2/)

Comment: How does this return a single `.tmpSelected` item per parent if there is no `.selected` and how does it only return one `.selected` per parent when there is no `.tempSelected`?

Comment: I have updated it now. I think that this is what the OP was asking.

Comment: @JohnKalberer won't this give me nothing if there are both `.selected` and `.tmpSelected` elements in the containing element? But I think this is the right track – `"ul > li.tmpSelected, ul:not(:has(li.tmpSelected)) > li.selected"` is the answer, do you agree?

Comment: @John Kalberer May be you should add yet another selector `ul:has(li.selected) > li.tempSelected` ? To get `tempSelected` if it has a `selected` sibling?

Comment: @kojiro yes, if you always want to grab `.tmpSelected` if it's there then you are correct

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this which is pretty similar in concept to what you already had except this guarantees that it only ever returns a single item for each parent.

```
var selected = $("#a, #b, #c").map(function() {
   var item = $(this).find(".tmpSelected");
   if (!item.length) {
       item = $(this).find(".selected");
   }
   return(item.get(0));
});
```

Comment: +1 Although I probably should've mentioned there never will be more than one of the `.selected/.tmpSelected` elements per `ul`. But it rarely hurts to be explicit!